# Invisible symbols in mingw console win11

Tags: intellij-idea, mingw-w64, windows-11, goland

I use `mingw` console(from gitbash) in `GoLand` from `JetBrains`(windows platform), when I use same thing with win 10, all was ok.

But now whenI start console often in console exist some invisible symbols like this:

`tsepi@laptop MINGW64 ~/GolandProjects/...`

`$ ls`

`bash: дls: command not found`

Its only at start, after in next commands all is ok. Has anyone encountered anything like this?

I dunno, why this happening. its regular and repeatable.